# Alert Box position changes in landscape mode

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have programmed an alert Controller for an application . It seems to work fine in all devices except in Moto X (android 5.1) .

In landscape mode , the alert box automatically positions itself to the right end of the screen.

The same thing happens when the virtual keyboard appears . It works well in other versions of android .

The alert box as such does not experience any change in position in other android versions .

**My Questions:**

What could be the possible work around ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

Comment: My issue is pertaining only to a specific android version , it works well in other cases .